# understanding this piece of python code do exactly?

Tags: python

I'm recently started to learn python and I'm playing with tweepy. now I'm kinda confused what this piece of code does especially the class part and what is passed to the class.

made some research about python classes and objects but still didn't get much out of it.

```
class PrintListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        tweet = json.loads(data)


        print('@%s: %s' % (tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')))

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
```

Comment: more on this part: `class PrintListener(tweepy.StreamListener):`
would like to know what is being passed to the class.

Comment: There are many things in this piece of code, there is a `class` `inheritance` `overriding` `json` and more. which part you don't get?

Comment: Or if its possible for you guys to explain what the entire code does line by line. i know its a lame question but could not find any better place to seek help from.

Comment: @ShahinShateri - I think you would be better off if you read a tutorial on Python.   Read about `class` declarations.  (Hint: `tweepy.StreamListener` is a superclass of `PrintListener`)

Comment: @StephenC thanks buddy. guess im starting to realize whats going on. and for sure will read more about python `class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Tweepy website](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/streaming_how_to.html):

> In Tweepy, an instance of tweepy.Stream establishes a streaming session and routes messages to StreamListener instance. The on_data method of a stream listener receives all messages and calls functions according to the message type. The default StreamListener can classify most common twitter messages and routes them to appropriately named methods, but these methods are only stubs.

So basically, upon success, the `on_data` method will receive the messages as a JSON file and print the tweet as well as information about the author.